# Ubuntu Core 16 on NUC7i3BNK

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-core, intel-nuc

I'm trying to install the AMD64 Ubuntu Core 16 image on a new NUC. The NUC has an internal NVMe drive. I have booted using the live image and copied the image to the internal NVMe and rebooted, the kernel starts but nothing much happens and I get "unable to resolve 'LABEL=writable'" errors, I never get to the configure screen.